# Call to undefined function Intervention\\Image\\Gd\\imagecreatefromjpeg() - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error message:

```
Call to undefined function Intervention\\Image\\Gd\\imagecreatefromjpeg()
```

this is my php info:

http://behika.com/

I'm using laravel framework (version 5.6) and php 7.1.

I want to upload a image but I got this error.

```
gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.6.32
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support
```

my store function:

```
public function store(CompanyRequest $request)
{
    $all = $request->except(['category-company', 'flag', 'null', 'file', 'producer-company','manager','address','description','phone']);
    $flag = array_values($request->input('flag'));
    $jsonFlag = json_encode($flag);
    $all['flag'] = $jsonFlag;

    if($request->input('manager')){
        $all['manager']=$request->input('manager');
    }
    if($request->input('address')){
        $all['address']=$request->input('address');
    }
    if($request->input('description')){
        $all['description']=$request->input('description');
    }
    if($request->input('phone')){
        $all['phone']=$request->input('phone');
    }
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $dir = '/img/company/';
    $path = $dir . time() . $name;
    $thumbnail = $dir . 'tn-' . time() . $name;
    $all['path'] = $path;
    $all['thumbnail'] = $thumbnail;


    $company = Company::create($all);

    $file->move('img/company', time() . $name);

    $img = Image::make('img/company/' . time() . $name);
    $img->resize(100, 100);
    $img->save('img/company/tn-' . time() . $name);


    $company->categories()->sync($request->input('category-company'));
    $company->producers()->sync($request->input('producer-company'));

    return Response::json($company);
}
```

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: updated my code.

Comment: $time = time(); Otherwise each time you call time(), the time could change!

Answer (score 39):

I had the same problem.  It took me some hours of tracing to get here, because [the Image Intervention code uses](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/master/src/Intervention/Image/Gd/Decoder.php#L36):

```
$core = @imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
```

So errors are suppressed.  Apache was throwing 500 responses but no messages about why, no logs, nothing.  Very frustrating!

The clue is in the GD support output you included above, which does not list JPG.  Mine was is similar - JPEG is listed but not shown as enabled:

```
// I'm using CLI here, use <?php print_r(gd_info()); ?> in an http php page
// to check your web server, CLI PHP config is different to web server config
php -r 'print_r(gd_info());'
Array
(
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] => 
    [T1Lib Support] => 
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] =>         // <------ blank
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] => 
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [WebP Support] => 
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

I am running PHP/Apache in a Docker container, and the solution for me was to add JPG support in my Dockerfile, as described [in the 'PHP Core Extensions' section of the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/):

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Now GD shows JPG support:

```
php -r 'print_r(gd_info());' 
Array
(
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] => 1
    [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype
    [T1Lib Support] => 
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] => 1         // <------ hurray!
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] => 
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [WebP Support] => 
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

And Image Intervention *finally* works!

Comment: It's not clear here. What did you do to add support or jpg in your dockerfile?

Comment: @KinsDotNet I've updated my answer, it is just copy-pasted from the section of the doc I linked to.

Comment: @KinsDotNet does that help?

Comment: It did. Thank you

Comment: Just updated my dockerfile as per his answer. It works. https://github.com/ssi-anik/docker-builds/commit/bbab30e31ae1453a2832bd4773d99dd2d70cd4b2

Comment: solution works, updated the docker fie, down/up (not just restart) and the JPEG support is added